# Prompting for a folder name in ssis using a vb script task

Tags: vb.net, ssis-2008

```
Public Sub Main()
    ' First create a FolderBrowserDialog object
    Dim FolderBrowserDialog1 As New FolderBrowserDialog

    ' Then use the following code to create the Dialog window
    ' Change the .SelectedPath property to the default location
    With FolderBrowserDialog1
        ' Desktop is the root folder in the dialog.
        '   .RootFolder = "C:\"
        ' Select the C:\Windows directory on entry.
        .SelectedPath = "c:\windows"
        ' Prompt the user with a custom message.
        .Description = "Select the source directory"
        If .ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            ' Display the selected folder if the user clicked on the OK button.
            MessageBox.Show(.SelectedPath)
        End If
    End With
```

The above is not showing me the dialog.  How to I get this to work?  I will be using the result in a for loop so I need to assign the result to a READWRITE variable

Comment: This is fascinating. I've never seen someone try to include user input in a ssis package before

Comment: are you sure you are triggering `main` ??

Comment: It seems to me that maybe.. after `.Description = "Select the source directory"`, you should insert `FolderBrowserDialog.Show`